# Consultar el estado de servidor NTP

Tags: java, android-studio

Se quiere validar el estado de un servidor NTP. Es decir, si este empieza a hacer consultas en un servidor fuera de línea, evidenciar que el proceso no fue correcto por que dicho servidor presenta problemas.

Hasta el momento solo sé que si el servidor no existe, este tomará un valor de null, por lo que validé así:

La variable timeServer hace referencia al servidor a consultar.

```
    String timeServer = "x";
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    InetAddress inetAddress = null;
```

Traemos la información de ese servidor

```
    try {
        inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(timeServer);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Una vez hecha la consulta de información, especificamos el tipo de datos que requerimos

```
    TimeInfo timeInfo = null;

    if (inetAddress != null) {
        try {
            timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Ahora lo que se desea validar es que si en la variable timeServer pasan una dirección de un servidor que ya no esta funcionando o una cadena a la cual no arrojará ninguna información, evidenciar un mensaje tipo "Error, no hay conexión con el servidor".

Answer (score 0):

En un investigación, pude deducir que para cumplir dicho proceso existen dos opciones:

- Tener condiciones root en el dispositivo para que el método isReachable(int timeout), que recibe como parámetro el tiempo en milisegundos y devolverá true si en ese tiempo de consulta el servidor devolvió la información solicitada para verificar su funcionalidad.
- Establecer una comunicación cliente-servidor por medio de protocolo UDP.
- Utilizar los recursos propios de la clase NTPUDPClient, donde por medio del método setDefaultTimeout(int timeout), que recibe por parámetro el tiempo en milisegundos que hace referencia a el tiempo que tiene establecido para consultar la información en el servidor **(mi elección)**.

El método lo ajusté de modo que me retornara un booleano dependiendo del estado del proceso. Es así que el proceso es propenso a fallar por lo que estará encapsulado en un try/catch:

```
    String timeServer = "x";
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    timeClient.setDefaultTimeout(5000);
    InetAddress inetAddress = null;
    TimeInfo timeInfo = null;

    try {
        inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(timeServer);
        timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        return true;
      } catch (IOException | NullPointerException | SDKException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Logger.information(e.getMessage());
        return false;
      }
```

Tener en cuenta que el comportamiento va en su proceso normal, por lo que es posible que dentro del try falle y gracias a la excepciones sugeridas, podemos saber donde y porqué falló.